# MySQL - what causes table row fragmentation

Tags: mysql, myisam

How does MySQL MyISAM store data per row when there is non-fixed length data?
Example, if a row contains a varchar, if that varchar is empty on insert but is later updated with 50 chars of data, could this effectively fragment that row?

How likely would that be?  If for example there were another 20 rows added after the insert and before the subsequent update of 50 chars, would that almost guarantee the updated row was now fragmented or what would affect the point where the row would become fragmented?

Comment: Not MyISAM, but you might find this interesting: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/

Comment: PostgreSQL-specific, but you might also find this interesting: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/storage-page-layout.html